# Laravel Like Query Issue

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

```
$a = table::select('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();
```

$term holds the value entered by user. My Issue is, the like does not work and it returns all results from the table irrespective of the word "$term".

If I do a query like -

```
$a = table::select('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%abc%')->get();
```

this works fine, but every time I pass Php variable, it does not work as expected. Can any one enlighten a bit on this.

EDIT --

I found the issue. My $term was not getting the value. Such a foolish issue.
Thank You every one who replied.

Comment: query is fine. its strange that it is not working?

Comment: Are you sure you were getting value within `$term`

Comment: please check out `$term` value. either it is `null` or having `white space`, or may be some `special character like slashes` etc.

Comment: Please close your question.

Comment: Thank You for your input, My $term was the issue. I dont have enough privileges to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure really whats wrong, it looks fine, you can also make use of [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) function, like below

```
 $a = table::select('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', sprintf("%%%s%%",$term))->get();

 // OR

 $a = table::select('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$term%")->get();
```

Comment: This also returns all results. Even I don't understand what is wrong. When I pass a string, it definitely gives the expected result.

Comment: whether `$term` is null ? I guess `$term` is issue

Comment: Yes. it was the issue. Thank You for getting me corrected.

Comment: Glad to know that you got solution

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is nothing wrong in your sql query 
I suggest you to check the value of `$term`

You may also try this:

```
$a = table::select("name")->where("name", "LIKE", "% $term %")->get();
```

OR

```
$a = table::select("name")->where("name", "LIKE", "% {$term} %")->get();
```

Comment: Same result. Also returns all results, irrespective of the term. :(

Comment: $term was the issue. I got it corrected, Thank You for replying,

Comment: No problems..  Keep coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Since query looks correct.
This may be it work.

```
$a = table::select('name')->where('name', 'LIKE', "%.$term.%")->get();
```

Comment: check if you are getting $term value as required by echo